# Laravel общие вопросы проектирования

Tags: php, laravel

1. Зачем нужны MiddleWare, если есть Events?
2. Можно ли создавать новый autoload (в композере) для классов Repositories например? Или в Laravel можно хранить подобные вещи еще где-то?
3. В модели допустимы ли методы, которые связаны только с обработкой полученной информации с БД? Или только ORM штучки?
4. Зачем вот нужны эти Repositories-классы? Что в них такого особенного, если есть модели?

Comment: Постарайтесь задавать вопросы по отдельности, а не сразу кучу в одном посте, при этом желательно более подробно раскрывать вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ларавел, конечно, ни ногой, но

- Middleware - это обработчик запроса, который встраивается в середину. Может докинуть в запрос текущий язык. Может просто собрать статистику. Может вообще прекратить выполнение. Единица выполнения - запрос, допустимые возможности - безграничны.
- Событие - эта такая штука, в момент которой может потребоваться выполнить еще какой-то функционал. Записать в лог регистрацию нового пользователя, отправить письмо всем заинтересованным в комментарии, сбросить кэш. Единица выполнения - произвольная, но более мелкая, чем запрос, допустимые возможности - обработка события не должна прерывать приложение в целом.

> В модели допустимы ли методы, которые связаны только с обработкой полученной информации с БД? Или только ORM штучки?
>   ...
>   Зачем вот нужны эти Repositories-классы? Что в них такого особенного, если есть модели?

По-хорошему *модельное сборище классов* должно отвечать за всю бизнес-логику и вся обработка и вызовы внешних сервисов должны происходить внутри. Другое дело, что там, похоже, ActiveRecord, в котором это все получится разве что отвратительно, а репозиториев я вообще не нашел. В идеале есть такая система: есть репозиторий, который заведует нахождением и хранением моделейй, а модель - это просто объект, представляющий какую-то сущность. Метод "отправить в бан" меняет у этой модели статус, а за его сохранение отвечает уже репозиторий. Но, повторюсь, мне не хватает документации, чтобы сказать, как это должно быть в laravel.

Answer (score 1):

1. Middleware (посредники) - это фильтры обработки HTTP-запроса, a
   Events - это простая реализация паттерна Observer (прочитать про события)
2. В Laravel пятой ветки есть такое понятие как "Service providers", просто нужно прочитать про них тебе подробнее.
3. Обрабатывать данные в модели, а зачем ? Есть сервисы и прочие штучки.
4. Тут я вообще не могу понять о чем речь.

Comment: Спасибо большое - почитаю)

Comment: 4. Патерн Репозиторий

Answer (score 0):

4. Насколько я понимаю, это сделано для удобства, но необязательно к использованию. Если например у модели 100 методов, логично побочные методы вынести в репозиторий. Из моего опыта - будет работать и так, и просто в модели если писать.