# Смысл Repository Pattern Laravel?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, laravel

Вот примитивный пример моего приложения:

```
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Interfaces\InterfaceRepository;

class RepositoryDictionary implements InterfaceRepository
{
    public $model;

    public function __construct(\Dictionary $model);

    public function find($id);

    public function all();

    public function byRaw($column, $st, $raw);

    public function update($id, array $sets);

}
```

Следовательно все это дело потом в контроллер:

```
class DictionaryController extends BaseController
{
    public $dictionary;

    public function __construct(RepositoryDictionary $repositoryDictionary)
    {
        $this->repositoryDictionary = $repositoryDictionary;
    }
}
```

А теперь вопрос: почему нельзя сделать вот так:

```
class DictionaryController extends BaseController
{
    public $dictionary;

    public function __construct(Dictionary $model)
    {
        $this->repositoryDictionary = $model;
    }
}
```

Репозиторий-класс же в себе ничего не хранит? Какой в нем толк?

Comment: Репозиторий класс просто дублирует методы модели

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/415954/16095

Comment: Вчера ночью я все же кажется как-то понял язык души программистов и ту самую суть этого паттерна! Он для наглядности, чтобы в контроллерах не было запросов с QueryBuilder-ов и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Репозиторий это прослойка, призванная упростить и сделать более наглядной работу с моделями, избавиться от специфических для DBAL (Eloquent) вызовов в контроллере. То есть в идеале вся работа с СУБД или еще каким хранилищем данных перемещается в репозитории.

Репозиторий добавляет наглядности и гибкости, но при этом увеличивает количество кода :) Как всегда в ООП.

Comment: То же самое можно сказать про active record. Вопрос про другое (а мне лень еще раз это писать).

Comment: если вопрос буквально "почему нельзя инжектить другое", то ответ: почему нельзя? — можно! )))  

мне показалось, что вопрос всё-таки про смысл. active record не прячет в себе ничего. между active record и repository сходство примерное как между скрипкой и филармонией.